# Google AI Platform for mathematical optimization

Tags: optimization, google-cloud-platform, mathematical-optimization, gurobi, google-ai-platform

I'm considering using the Google AI ​​Platform on GCP.
But, I don't use a Machine Learning Algorithm, in the other hand, I use some mathematical optimization.
So, I'm using 'Gurobi Optimization' to solve our optimization problem.

My question is:

1. In my case (only use mathematical optimization case), do you think will work to use AI Platform? (I think it is attractive to use a notebook, pipeline and what-if tool.)
2. Can I connect to the Gurobi optimization server (on Compute Engine) from AI Platform?